# Converting .htaccess to web.config

Tags: asp.net, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I am currently in the process of moving from parallels plesk for centos to parallels plesk for windows.  The only snag i've hit is I realized .htaccess won't work anymore.
Here was my .htaccess:

```
options -indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^(verify)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ validate_account.php?usr=$3&hash=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(post)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ news.php?post=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^uploads/avatars/(.+)$ ../uploads/avatars/$1 [L,NC]

Redirect 301 /signup /register

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

errordocument 404 /404.php
errordocument 403 /404.php
errordocument 500 /404.php

allow from all
#deny from all
#allow from 98.115.168.25
deny from 162.144.91.203 #attempted brute force
deny from 74.208.100.64 #attempted brute force
deny from 185.57.82.25 #tried to ddos
```

Here is the web.config I generated with a website:

```
<rule name="rule 1F">
    <match url="^(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2F" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(verify)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/validate_account.php?usr={R:3}&amp;hash={R:4}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3F" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(post)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/news.php?post={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4F" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^uploads/avatars/(.+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/../uploads/avatars/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 5F">
    <match url="(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 6F" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}"  />
</rule>
```

It gives me 500 internal server error whenever I try accessing the site, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
<rule name="rule 1X">
        <match url="^(.*)$"  />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php"  />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rule 2X" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(verify)/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$"  />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/validate_account.php?usr={R:3}&amp;hash={R:4}"  appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rule 3X" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(post)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/news.php?post={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rule 4X" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^uploads/avatars/(.+)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/../uploads/avatars/{R:1}"  />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rule 5X">
        <match url="(.*)"  />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"  />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rule 6X" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^"  />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}"  />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Responds with:

HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Detailed Error Information
Module RewriteModule
Notification BeginRequest
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x800700a1
Requested URL http://domain.com:80/
Physical Path C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs
Logon Method Not yet determined
Logon User Not yet determined

Comment: Have you installed the IIS URL Rewrite Module?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the free version of [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) I was able to use .htaccess with IIS 7.